# selenium testcase failing with IE browser while it's working fine with chrome and firefox

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, testng

While I am executing testcases (Selenium WebDriver + Java) on **Internet explorer** i am getting exception "**unhandledAlertException**" and testcases getting failed while it's working fine with Chrome and Firefox browser. Also having issue like: sometimes it click on element and respond accordingly and sometimes its clicked but did not respond with same code.

Here is some code from where it was throwing "**unhandledAlertException**"

```
protected void clickOnElement(WebElement element)
    {
        if(isElementPresent(element))
        {
            if(getBrowserName().equalsIgnoreCase("internet explorer")){
                element.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
                wait(2000);
                System.out.println("In IE clicked on element");
            }else{
                element.click();
            }
        implicitWait(Integer.parseInt(ConfigParser.getProperty("common_wait_timeout")));
        }
    }
```

**unhandledAlertException** is now resolved by removing implicit wait from code. **but sometimes unresponsiveness of elements in IE is still persist.**

How can overcome from such issues with **IE**

Comment: can you please share your code with question?

Comment: Anyhow you can catch the unhandledAlertException and for elements try to put more wait time. If then also they are unable to click try using JavascriptExecutor in case of IE.

Comment: By removing implicit wait from code unhandledAlertException is resolved. I wonder why it was throwing this exception. But sometimes unresponsiveness of elements on IE is still persist for same code.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding proper wait conditinos in your code for IE browser. Generally IE doesnt respond well. Also have a look at the element Id's in IE they might be changing.

Answer (score 0):

IE will always have issues with selenium webdriver. Microsoft itself doesn't maintain IE driver for selenium like chrome and FF. You best chances are to use proper wait.

Answer (score 0):

What version of IE are you using? There are known issues with the latest versions of IE with Selemium. I faced similar issues and had to switch back to IE8. Also are you getting the exception after the browser is launched? Tip: Under IE options, make sure all the modes are enabled under the security tab and the zoom is set to 100%.

Hope this helps.. good luck!!

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase(IE)) {
  System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", getRootDir() + "/src/main/java/configuration/IEDriverServer.exe");
  driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

you have to download IEDriverServer.exe and set the path in the above, and then get the driver of IE, it will work fine and i hope you will get any problem if it is even IE 11/click problem.